# CSS overflow-y is not working as advertised?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to get my top sentence (`<p>geornvgowegnoewpgnerognm</p>`) to be hidden inside a div and I'm not sure if this is possible but one thing for sure is that the `overflow-y` style is not working as expected, or maybe I'm doing something terribly wrong. Basically I expect no scroll bar and I get a horizontal one even though [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) says it should hide the content horizontally. I'm using Firefox 28 beta but that shouldn't matter no?

Here's the code,

```
<html>
<head>  
</head> 
<body>
<style type = "text/css">
#div_1
{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: white;
}
body
{
    background-color: black;
}
p
{
    font-color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<div id = "div_1">
<p>geornvgowegnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>eornvgowegnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>ornvgowegnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>rnvgowegnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>nvgowegnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>vgowegnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>gowegnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>owegnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>wegnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>egnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>gnoewpgnerognm</p>
<p>noewpgnerognm</p>
<p>oewpgnerognm</p>
<p>ewpgnerognm</p>
<p>wpgnerognm</p>
<p>pgnerognm</p>
<p>gnerognm</p>
<p>nerognm</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, I'm trying to make the top sentence hidden in my div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it is

1) Visually hide the paragraph tag. It will keep it's space in the div as though its there, just not visible.

```css
#div_1 p:first-child {visibility: hidden;}
```

or 2) visually remove the paragraph tag. It look as though it's not there, all other paragraph tags will move up in it's place.

```css
#div_1 p:first-child {display: none;}
```

Comment: Edited to add syntax highlighting hints so your code isn't all grayed out ^_^

Comment: Also, you should probably explain what's different between the two codes - what changes if you use one or the other?

Comment: I understand the codes although someone else might not. I think Zack is really smart by the way for seeing this.

Comment: Sorry guys, new to SO. I've updated with some more clear comments.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the horizontal scrollbar, use overflow-x:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

overflow-y, hides the overflow in the `y` direction. As in up and down, which would hide a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to hide the top sentence in the div though? It's fine if the answer is no.

Comment: What do you mean 'hide the top sentence'? To you mean make it so that it doesn't show at all, or so that it gets cut off? If you want to hide your first <p>, use the answer from @zack